# SASS variables in a mixin

Tags: css, variables, sass, mixins

I am not sure how to explain my question but here it is:

I have a collection of variables that contain colors related to categories

$apples: red

$sky: blue

$oranges: orange
etc

Then I have a mixin that I want to apply these colors only when there is a class with the variable name in it:

```
=category-color($cat)
  .category-#{$cat}
    .title
      color: $cat
```

this is outputting as:

```
.category-apples .title {color: apples;}
```

Is it possible to make this work? or do I need to make each of them?